# How to Open webpage with forms filled out using python?

Tags: python, forms

It's really complicated to fully mechanize submitting a form in a website (captcha's, cookies, etc) so I want to open a specific url with all the forms filled out and submit it manually.

For example the url's html is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" required value=""/>
```

and I want something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" required value="3423534456"/>
```

I would like the browser to "add" some things to the html code but open it on the same url, like adblock opens a url's html but without some parts of the code.

And I want to use python in order to mechanize the filling out of the forms.

How can I do that?

Comment: By visiting the url directly you can't really escape prerequisites security features like captchas, cookies etc... if you could that would be probably considered a security vulnerability.

Comment: I don't want to escape them. I want to inject things into the html code...

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to do with pure python. The browser doesn't run python code so it will be very complex to inject something in the browser without using at least javascript.

That said, you can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to drive a browser.  Here's a simple example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: I tried it a lot, but I found it to be very troublesome. The best solution so far is injecting javascript in the webpage via console. I use python to write all forms fillable with javascript in a text file. I copy each line and paste it in the console and then solve the captcha and submit it by hand.